# gt package native grouping strategies for multiple hierarchical categories and quantitative data

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

I am working on a gt table solution to avoid duplicating values. I like how gt handles native grouping with row groups; however, with the sample dataset and example code, variables Type, Speed, and L are duplicated when grouping the data by Object, unless they are used as a row group label. Using row group to column in gt seems to create row groups that are too wide, and causes issues as multiple row group labels are added. I've seen some solutions in the gt cookbook that suggest deleting duplicate data, but this also does not work with these data, and perhaps is not an ideal way to handle this.

In the sample dataset below, the variables Type, Speed, and L are attributes of each Object. Each object has multiple sensors. A and B are values for each sensor:

```
#load required packages
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

#define sample dataset
sensors <- structure(list(Object = c("obj_1", "obj_1", "obj_2", "obj_2", 
"obj_3", "obj_3"), Type = c("E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), Speed = c(24, 
24, 25, 25, 24, 24), L = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Sensor = c("sen_1", 
"sen_2", "sen_1", "sen_3", "sen_4", "sen_2"), A = c(1, NA, 1, 
1, 2, NA), B = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = 
structure(list(
cols = list(Object = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Speed = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), L = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Sensor = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), A = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), B = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 
    0x0000020901c753c0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#Table with Objects as groups
sensors %>%
gt(rowname_col = c("Sensor"), groupname_col = c("Object")) %>% 
tab_spanner(
  label = "By Location",
  columns = c(A, B)
  )
```

[image]

The best solution to avoid duplicated data I've found is to add these variables to the row group; however, in my opinion the information is obscured this way. I've made the object name bold to get around this but I still don't think this is a great solution:

```
row_group_sep <- " - "

sensors %>%
gt(rowname_col = c("Sensor"), groupname_col = c("Object", "Type", "Speed", "L")) %>% 
tab_spanner(
  label = "By Location",
  columns = c(A, B)
) %>%
gt::text_transform(
  locations = cells_row_groups(),
  fn = function(x) {
    lapply(x, function(x) {
      x <- strsplit(x, split = row_group_sep)[[1]]
      gt::md(paste0("**", x[[1]], "**", row_group_sep, x[[2]], row_group_sep, x[[3]], 
      row_group_sep, x[[4]]))
      })
     }
    )
```

[image]

Is there a more reader friendly way of using gt to display the values of "Type", "Speed", and "L" besides in a row group like this while still avoiding duplicating their values in the final table? Perhaps there is a simple solution to achieve what I show in the image below, with the data crossed out in red removed or not displayed?

[image]